# Does web3js support Bitcoin

Tags: ethereum, bitcoin, web3js, geth

A quick question. I used web3js lib to create an app in which a user can create his own account and also a wallet. My question is is that wallet can be used only with the ethereum coin transfer or can I use to store or transfer btc as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

web3.js is strictly Ethereum specific library. It shares some of the cryptographic library dependencies with Bitcoin, but if you plan to create a non-custodial Bitcoin wallet there are better JavaScript libraries as starting points out there.

Comment: "better JavaScript libraries" such as?

Comment: Bitcoin has its dedicated StackExchange. Try there of StackOverflow.com if you have a question.

Comment: @galki for multichain support I think Trust Wallet Core would be good, it has wasm for browser environment https://github.com/trustwallet/wallet-core